# I am getting 'SystemExit: 2' error , how to fix it

Tags: python, systemexit

I am new to the machine learning coding . I am trying to run the code to find the number people in the video , image or by the live camera, but I am getting error
I am using Collab notebook to run it

```
'''
if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOGCV = cv2.HOGDescriptor()
    HOGCV.setSVMDetector(cv2.HOGDescriptor_getDefaultPeopleDetector())
    args = argsParser()
    humanDetector(args) '''
```

I am getting this error

```
'''
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [-v VIDEO] [-i IMAGE] [-c CAMERA]
                             [-o OUTPUT]
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -f /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/kernel-53a4a604-58e1-45bc-94ff-0a7c8720f3dc.json
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2 '''
```

I excepted it should run using image , video and camera in collab notebook`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to add in the end of " arg_parse.add_argument " line ( This is the reason you are getting 'SystemExit: 2' error ):**

```
parser.add_argument("-f", required=False)
```

Edit your argsParser like this:

```
def argsParser():
  arg_parse = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  arg_parse.add_argument("-v", "--video", default='your_video_path', help="path to Video File ")
  arg_parse.add_argument("-i", "--image", default='your_image_path', help="path to Image File ")
  arg_parse.add_argument("-c", "--camera", default='True/False', help="Set True if you want to use the camera.")
  arg_parse.add_argument("-o", "--output", type=str, default='your_output_path', help="path to optional output video file")
  arg_parse.add_argument("-f", required=False)

  args = vars(arg_parse.parse_args())

  return args
```

Now you can call:

```
args = argsParser()
humanDetector(args)
```